# How to do google translation realtime on SwiftUI Text and other components

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, google-mlkit

how to use this function to translate a string and reassign to Text UI

```
 func translate() {
        let options = TranslatorOptions(sourceLanguage: sourceLanguage, targetLanguage: destinationLanguage)
        let translator = Translator.translator(options: options)
        let conditions = ModelDownloadConditions(allowsCellularAccess: true, allowsBackgroundDownloading: true)
        translator.downloadModelIfNeeded(with: conditions) { error in
            guard error == nil else { return }
            translator.translate(languageTranslationText) { translatedText, error in
                guard error == nil, let translatedText = translatedText else { return }
                print(translatedText)
            }
        }
        
    }
```

how to use google translator in Swift UI project.

```
struct TextUILabel: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    var font: UIFont?
    var color: UIColor?

   func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UILabel {
       let textLabel = UILabel()

       textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       textLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
       textLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
       textLabel.textColor = color ?? .black
       return textLabel
   }

   func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: Context) {
       
       let options = TranslatorOptions(sourceLanguage: GoogleTranslatorManager.shared.sourceLanguage, targetLanguage: GoogleTranslatorManager.shared.destinationLanguage)
       let conditions = ModelDownloadConditions(allowsCellularAccess: true, allowsBackgroundDownloading: true)
       GoogleTranslatorManager.shared.translator?.downloadModelIfNeeded(with: conditions) { error in
           guard error == nil else { return }
           GoogleTranslatorManager.shared.translator?.translate(text) { translatedText, error in
               guard error == nil, let translatedText = translatedText else {
                   uiView.text = text
                   return
               }
               print(translatedText)
               uiView.text = translatedText
               if let textFont = font {
                   uiView.font = textFont
               }
           }
       }
}
```

I tried with this, but I have to redesign all UI with help of UI kit, that is not good